# $\iiint \sqrt{x^2+z^2}\,dx\,dy\,dz$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

$$\iiint \sqrt{x^2+z^2}\,dx\,dy\,dz$$
I am asked to evaluate this integral over the region $$D:=\left \{ (x,y,z) \in\mathbb{R}^3 :x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq 1 \wedge x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq 2y\right \}$$
I did manage to visualize what this region looks like, however, I am uncertain about how to approach the problem. Do I use Cartesian coordinates or do I switch to spherical? What would be the most effective method?

**EDIT**: I have managed to swap to spherical coordinates, and I have set up the bounds for two of the three parameters, I am just unable to do it for the third, namely, $\phi$. I suppose it is from zero to $\pi/2$, but I keep getting the wrong answer.

**EDIT 2:** As suggested in the comments, I swapped the $y$ and $z$ variables(though, this was not necessary), and then made another change to cylindricals. Here is the integral I set up:
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{\frac{3}{4}}}\int_{1+\sqrt{1-\rho^{2}}}^{\sqrt{1-\rho^{2}}}\rho^{2}dzd \rho d\theta$$
Where $\rho$ is the radial distance ind $\theta$ is the angle. Using this swap of variables is far easier than to use sphericals, however I still can't manage to get the answer to be 0.62(as suggested in one of the answers). I have a feeling that the boundaries for the $z$ variable are a little bit off here.

Comment: I would swap y and z, and then switch to cylindrical.

Comment: I had that in mind too! Care to write down as answer?

Comment: Why is the [tag:surface-integrals] tag being used here?  Is there a surface integral I missed?

Comment: That tag needs to be removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The volume you want to integrate is the rotation of this volume:

[image]

So you got it right save for a minus sign:

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{\frac{3}{4}}}\int_{1+\sqrt{1-\rho^{2}}}^{\sqrt{1-\rho^{2}}}\rho^{2}dzd \rho d\theta$$

Should have been:

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{\frac{3}{4}}}\int_{1-\sqrt{1-\rho^{2}}}^{\sqrt{1-\rho^{2}}}\rho^{2}dzd \rho d\theta$$

which is indeed $$\frac{\pi ^2}{6}-\frac{1}{16} \left(3 \sqrt{3} \pi \right)\approx0.62$$

Comment: Doesn't seem intuitive at first. Had to write the equations one more time, and be careful. Rearranging the equation of the upper sphere written in cylindricals  I got $\left | z-1 \right |=\sqrt{1-\rho^{2}}$. For the absolute value part, we took the negative possible solution, because in the region we are integrating over $z-1$ is always nonpostive?

Comment: We get a negative sign because we want to bottom half of the circle

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Swap y and z, and then switch to cylindrical. The numerical value should be about 0.62, you can check it afterwards.

Comment: Hi, I have instead opted to switch to spherical coordinates. However I am uncertain about getting the right bounds for the angle $\phi$

Comment: Cylindrical is the way to go. You have $r^2+z^2<1$ and $r^2+z^2<2z$. Rearrange them and you'll get $r^2+(z-1)^2<1$ http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ContourPlot%5B%7Br%5E2%2Bz%5E2%3C1%2Cr%5E2%2B%28z-1%29%5E2%3C1%7D%2C%7Br%2C-1%2C1%7D%2C%7Bz%2C-1%2C1%7D%5D Keep in mind, r is always positive. You need to integrate it for $0<r<\frac{\sqrt3}{2}$

Comment: On a side note, using my method I got twice the volume that you suggested.

Comment: Write the definite integral here. I am quite sure about my result.

Comment: $\int_{0}^{2\cos \theta }\rho ^{3}d\rho \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin ^{2}\left ( \theta \right )d\theta\int_{0}^{2\pi}d\varphi $ (note that some people use $\theta$ and $\varphi$ interchangeably. Here $\phi$represents the horizontal angle.

Comment: First of all, you can't write triple integrals like that. The result of the $\rho$ integral is a function of $\theta$, so you need to write it inside the $\theta$ integral. You also forgot about the $r^2<1$ constrain. When $\theta=\pi/2$ you have $0<r<2$ which you cannot have. The correct integral is this: $$2 \pi  \left(\int _0^{\cos ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}\int _0^1r^3 \sin ^2(t)drdt+\int _{\cos ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}^{\frac{\pi }{2}}\int _0^{2 \cos (t)}r^3 \sin ^2(t)drdt\right)$$ Also, the integral you have written does not give $2\times 0.62$, it is $\pi^2/4$

Comment: Which turns out to be: $$\frac{\pi ^2}{6}-\frac{1}{16} \left(3 \sqrt{3} \pi \right)$$